# Understanding "driverless" USB HID

Tags: usb, hid

I'm at the beginning of trying to develop a USB HID bootloader for a Kinetis processor, and getting no help from that department. I have made some modifications to Kinetis firmware designed for a similar processor(I'm using the KL26Z, the original code is for KL25Z), and I do now see the beginning of the USB enumeration(on a PC running W7). However, the PC asks for driver software, and I don't understand why, as I thought the whole point of going the HID route was that one didn't need to install drivers. So the device shows up under device manager, but as a non-working problem device. My problem is that I don't really know what should happen. Any insights would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what should happen: the computer will ask your device for its USB descriptors when it detects your device.  The descriptors must have certain fields like bDeviceClass set properly to indicate that it is an HID.  If the computer sees those fields, it will attach the HID driver to your device.

In the Device Manager, you should look at the "Compatible Ids" of your device.  Do you see `USB\Class_03` in that list?  If so, that should match the driver `input.inf` that comes with Windows, so the INF file will be applied to your device, and you device will show up as "USB Input Device" in the Device Manager.  If you don't see `USB\Class_03` in your list then there is probably some problem with your device's USB descriptors or its USB stack.